# Jogl, creating only red channel u16 but getting "Texture type and format combination is not valid"

Tags: textures, jogl, opengl-3, short, picking

So, I am trying to implement the picking through id. This means with every drawArray a different unique id will be set as uniform and saved in the red component on a texture.

16 bits are more than enough (65k elements), so I choose to use shorts, I know that uniform variable can be only ui, but I decided to gave it a try anyway

I also found another question, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961098/precise-control-over-texture-bits-in-glsl), where the answer contains a small example with shorts

However here my code to initialize the framebuffer and two textures, one for the depth and one for the color_attachment0 with just the red component with 16

```
        textures = new int[2];
        fbo = new int[1];

        gl3.glGenTextures(2, textures, 0);
        gl3.glGenFramebuffers(1, fbo, 0);
        /**
         * Depth.
         */
        gl3.glBindTexture(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, textures[depth]);

        gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL3.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL3.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL3.GL_NEAREST);
        gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL3.GL_NEAREST);

        gl3.glTexImage2D(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL3.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT32F, width, height, 0, GL3.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, GL3.GL_FLOAT, null);
        /**
         * IDs.
         */
        gl3.glBindTexture(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, textures[id]);

        gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL3.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL3.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL3.GL_NEAREST);
        gl3.glTexParameteri(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL3.GL_NEAREST);

        gl3.glTexImage2D(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL3.GL_R16UI, width, height, 0, GL3.GL_RED, GL3.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, null);
        /**
         * FBO.
         */
        gl3.glBindFramebuffer(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fbo[0]);
        gl3.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL3.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, textures[depth], 0);
        gl3.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL3.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL3.GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, textures[id], 0);
```

I get the following error at the id-glTexImage2D

```
GLDebugEvent[ id 0x502
    type Error
    severity High: dangerous undefined behavior
    source GL API
    msg GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. Texture type and format combination is not valid.
    when 1391769197680
    source 4.4 (Compat profile, arb, debug, ES2 compat, ES3 compat, FBO, hardware) - 4.4.0 - hash 0x1c19b340]
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1364)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDebugMessageHandler$StdErrGLDebugListener.messageSent(GLDebugMessageHandler.java:308)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDebugMessageHandler.sendMessage(GLDebugMessageHandler.java:293)
at jogamp.opengl.GLDebugMessageHandler.glDebugMessageARB(GLDebugMessageHandler.java:319)
at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.dispatch_glTexImage2D1(Native Method)
at jogamp.opengl.gl4.GL4bcImpl.glTexImage2D(GL4bcImpl.java:27313)
at javax.media.opengl.DebugGL4bc.glTexImage2D(DebugGL4bc.java:19874)
at ec.rendering.input.picking.EC_Picking.initRenderingTargets(EC_Picking.java:107)
```

For completeness, here the VS:

```
#version 330

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

uniform mat4 modelToWorldMatrix;

layout(std140) uniform GlobalMatrices {
    mat4 worldToCameraMatrix;
    mat4 cameraToClipMatrix;
};

void main() {

    gl_Position = cameraToClipMatrix * (worldToCameraMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0));
}
```

modelToWorldMatrix is not yet taken in account at the moment

And here the FS:

```
#version 330

uniform uint id;

out vec4 outputColor;

void main() {

    outputColor = vec4(id, 0, 0, 1);
}
```

Using shorts is feasible?

Jogl, Opengl 3.3

Edit: it looks now I solved that part with

```
gl3.glTexImage2D(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL3.GL_R16I, width, height, 0, GL3.GL_RED_INTEGER, GL3.GL_SHORT, null);
```

but now I get an error when I try to set the short uniform value

```
gl3.glUniform1i(pickModel.getIdUL(), (int)mesh.getId());
```

Error

```
GLDebugEvent[ id 0x502
    type Error
    severity High: dangerous undefined behavior
    source GL API
    msg GL_INVALID_OPERATION error generated. Wrong component type or count.
    when 1391779682993
    source 4.4 (Compat profile, arb, debug, ES2 compat, ES3 compat, FBO, hardware) - 4.4.0 - hash 0x5ee072e3]
```

The uniform location seems correct since it is not -1 (1 actually)...

So how could I upload a short?

Comment: Are there any additional questions or feedback to the already existing answers or have you already solved the problem yourself?

Comment: @ChristianRau no, I didnt, because I had inconsistences even just with the clearing color http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/183630-Encoding-id-picking-into-a-16b-red-component-texture?p=1257745#post1257745 so I decided to give up..

Answer (score 0):

Most of your problems are related to the fact that OpenGL isn't as gracious with conversions as you might expect it to be.

First of all for a `glUniform` call the type and size of the uniform variable has to match the function exactly. Specifically, [the documentation](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glUniform.xhtml) says:

> `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` is generated if one of the signed integer
>   variants of this function is used to load a uniform variable of type
>   unsigned int, uvec2, uvec3, uvec4, or an array of these.

Thus you have to use `glUniform1ui` instead (mind the **u**!) if your `id` variable is a `uint`.

---

Other than that there's also a mismatch between your framebuffer's output format and your shader's output format. If you want to write into an integer texture, you need to write actual integers from your shader, thus change your `outputColor` to

```
out int outputID;
```

or maybe

```
out ivec4 outputID;
```

if neccessary (or with a "u" if using `GL_R16UI` of course).

---

And by the way, are you sure you need a signed integer texture (as unsigned would be much more natural for your use case)? You say that changing the `glTexImage2D` call to

```
gl3.glTexImage2D(GL3.GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE, 0, GL3.GL_R16I, width, height, 0, GL3.GL_RED_INTEGER, GL3.GL_SHORT, null);
```

made the texture error disappear, but this may very well have been because of the use of `GL_RED_INTEGER` instead of just `GL_RED` and not necessarily because of the use of a signed format. So `GL_R16UI` together with `GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT` and `GL_RED_INTEGER` (and of course a `uint` or `uvec4` for the output variable) would be worth a try.

Just keep in mind that the types always have to match.

Comment: Hi Christian, thanks for your answer, it is absolutely worth to give a try, anyway I would like you to take a look at this post of mine and tell me what you think about the clear on an int (short/int/u whatever) texture. http://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/183630-Encoding-id-picking-into-a-16b-red-component-texture?p=1257745#post1257745