# Texture splatting more than 5 textures

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx, textures, shader

I'm looking for a solution to store more than 5 diffrent texture in one chunk of a terrain and I've found part of this solution only. I have to pack all my textures (512x512) into one big texture (8192x8192) then in shader I have to calculate texture id using r,g,b values from splat texture. But how to calculate this id from r,g,b values. What is a formula?
[image]

Comment: I have very little idea what you're talking about.

Comment: why both OpenGL and DirectX tags?  what is splatting? Didi you mean blending instead? You know there is usually more than one texture unit... You can combine more textures by blending and rendering all the stuff over itself with different texture each pass... Or use more Texture units at once with either texture combination unit or shader code. I agree it is unclear what you want so +Close for now...

Comment: I've edited my post :)

Comment: (1) why don't you use array textures instead -- it would be so much easier wrt. to filtration. (2) what do you plan to do at placed where three or four textures meet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you got map (left texture/image) where **ID's** of surface type is stored per terrain segment. Than you have texture atlas (right texture) with `16x16=256` textures and want to produce combined texel for terrain coloring (bottom image).

1. **map texture**

   You did not specify its format and encoding but I suspect that is what you ask for.  So you got `256` textures meaning you need `8bit` per each **ID**. If you use `32bit` **RGBA** integer format you can store up to 4 **ID's**.
2. **encoding/decoding**

   If you need more then that use either more map textures or lover the number of textures in atlas. For example for 5 IDs you have `floor(32/5)=6 bits/ID` so you would need to have max `64` textures in your atlas (but still got 2 spare bits left so one **ID** could still use `256` or two **ID's** could use `128` textures.)

   Of coarse for all this you need integer sampling for map texture so just in case see:

   - [Precise control over texture bits in GLSL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15496462/2521214)

   instead of floating `r,g,b` values. The math equation on integers for `5` **IDs** **GPU decoding** from `r8g8b8a8` format could look like this (untested just illustrative):

   ```cpp
   uniform usampler2D tex;
   uvec4 a=texture(tex, ...); // fetch 4x8 bits
   uint b=0; // construct 32 bit int
   b|=uint(a.r);
   b|=uint(a.g)<<8;
   b|=uint(a.b)<<16;
   b|=uint(a.a)<<32;
   uint ID1=(b    )&0x3F; // decode ID's
   uint ID2=(b>> 6)&0x3F;
   uint ID3=(b>>12)&0x3F;
   uint ID4=(b>>18)&0x3F;
   uint ID5=(b>>24)&0x3F;
   ```

   And similarly **CPU encoding**:

   ```cpp
   uint a=0; // construct 32 bit int
   a|=(ID1&0x3F);
   a|=(ID2&0x3F)<< 6;
   a|=(ID3&0x3F)<<12;
   a|=(ID4&0x3F)<<18;
   a|=(ID5&0x3F)<<24;
   map_texture_data[...]=a;
   ```

   The codes are not tested so there may by reverse **RGBA** order or wrongly assumed `uint` bit-widths (they should match the rem-ed values.

Comment: Thank you, it's very helpful :)